# how to pass id from html tag list to jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, laravel

I have a table with this fields:
`id----candidate_id-----company_id----tag---`

My `controller` to store and remove a tag:

```
class CandidateTagController extends Controller
{
  public function store($candidate_id,$tag_text)
{
    $company_id = auth()->user()->company_id;

    $tag=new CandidateTag();

    $tag->company_id=$company_id;
    $tag->candidate_id=$candidate_id;
    $tag->tag=$tag_text;

    $tag->save();

    return $tag;

}
public function remove($tag_id)
{
    $tag_delete=CandidateTag::where('id','=',$tag_id)->delete();
    return back();
}
}
```

this is a part of my `blade` that show tag list:

```
  <div class="skill-tags">

            <ul id="tag-list">
                @foreach($tags as $tag)
                    <li>{{$tag->tag}}<a class="close-tag"><i class="icon-x"></i></a></li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
            <div class="skill-add-field">
                <i class="icon-plus"></i>
                <input id="candidateId" name="candidateId" type="hidden" value="{{$candidateProfile->id}}">
                <input id="tag-btn" maxlength="50" name="candidateTag" autocomplete="off"
                       placeholder="add new tag">
            </div>
        </div>
```

and this is apart of my `js` file:

```
$('#tag-btn').keyup(function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        var id = $('#candidateId').val();
        var text = $('#tag-btn').val();
        if(text!==''){
            var close = '<li>' + text + '<a class="close-tag"><i 
class="icon-x"></i></a></li>';
            $('#tag-list').append(close);
            $('#tag-btn').val('');
            // ajax function to pass data to controller
            $.ajax({
                url:"/panel/addtag/"+ id +"/"+ text,
                type: "GET", // not POST, laravel won't allow it
                data:{candidate_id:id ,tag: text},
                success: function(data){
                    //
                }
            });
        }
    }
});

$("#tag-list").on( "click", ".close-tag", function(){
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

how I should get `tag_id` from `tag list` and pass `tag_id` to remove function in `controller`?

Comment: `<a class="close-tag" data-tag-id="{{ $tag->id }}">`, and in js get id using, `$(this).data('tag-id')`.